# Append Data to the end of a row in a csv file (Python)

Tags: python, csv

I am attempting to append 4 elements to the end of a row in a csv file

```
Original
toetag1,tire11,tire12,tire13,tire14

Desired Outcome
toetag1,tire11,tire12,tire13,tire14,wtire1,wtire2,wtire3,wtire4
```

I attempted to research ways to do this how ever most search results yielded results such as "how to append to a csv file in python"

Can someone direct me in the correct way to solve this problem

Comment: "I attempted to research ways to do this". Where is your code that implements (or at least tries to implement) what you've researched?

Comment: My problem isnt that I cant implement the solutions that I have found my problem is that I cant find something to try to implement, if you search how to append to an existing row in a csv file you get things like this https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-append-to-a-csv-file-in-python

Comment: I would recommend reading up on basic Python file operations (open a file, move to the end of the file, write to the file). Searching on "append to a CSV file" is very specific and what you are trying to do is more generically "I want to append to a file".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise you to use pandas module and read_csv method.

You can use the following code for instance :

```
data = pandas.read_csv("your_file.csv")
row = data.iloc[0].to_numpy()
row.append(['wtire1','wtire2','wtire3','wtire4'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read the csv file to a list of lists and do the necessary manipulation before writing it back.

```
import csv

#read csv file
with open("original.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = [row for row in reader]

#modify data
data[0] = data[0] + ["wtire1", "wtire2", "wtire3", "wtire4"]

#write to new file
with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(data)
```