# How do I Edit A Certain Column or Row in a .CSV using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm currently working on a project that involves a spreadsheet. I need to append to an already existing .csv file and add items to a certain column and row using pandas. I'm aware of how to find certain columns and rows when reading: `.loc` or `.iloc`. However, I cannot find a way to ***write*** to a certain column and row.

```
import pandas
item = 'melon'
WriteItems = pandas.DataFrame({
    'Item': [item]
})
WriteItems.to_csv('ItemLog.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False)
```

When writing, it always places the `[item]` one row below the other data (which is in the first column). Is there a way to write [item] say, at (3,3)?

I got this idea from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68170398/append-data-to-the-end-of-a-row-in-a-csv-file-python) question's answer:

```
import pandas
item = 'melon'
data = pandas.read_csv('ItemLog.csv')
row = data.iloc[3, 1].to_numpy()
row.append([Item])
```

but got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/my/script", line 46, in <module>
    row = data.iloc[3, 1].to_numpy()
AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be arbitrarily modifying certain cells, then reading the CSV, modifying it, and then overwriting it, will be simplest.

```
import pandas as pd
item = 'melon'
data = pd.read_csv('ItemLog.csv')
data.iat[3, 1] = item
data.to_csv('ItemLog.csv', index=False)
```

If you really do want to append, I would do:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'Item': [item]
})

data = pd.read_csv('ItemLog.csv', nrows=0)
data = pd.concat([data, df])
data.to_csv('ItemLog.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False)
```